# Reset CSS background image

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create an accordion type menu using the following JQUERY:

```
function initMenu() {
    $('#menu ul').hide();
        $('#menu li a').click(
            function() {
                $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
                $(this).css("background", "url(customnav_selected.png) top right");
            }
        );
}
$(document).ready(function() {initMenu();});
```

This works to a point, when i click the menu link it expands and the menu header background changes.

However I want it to change back when I click it for a second time to collapse the menu.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
$(this).css("background", "url(customnav_selected.png) top right");
```

Put that style into a CSS class, and use [toggleClass](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/toggleClass) instead of [css](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS), e.g.:

```
$(this).toggleClass("selected"); //assuming a class of .selected
```

so the click handler becomes:

```
$('#menu li a').click(function() {
     $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
     $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

and the style:

```
<style>
.selected  {background: url(customnav_selected.png) top right} 
</style>
```

Comment: Thats just perfection - If only I knew Jquery a little better.

Comment: @Dhumperson, Consider accepting this as the answer if it met your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Set background-image to none (or to the initial value).

I find it easier to set classes to specific html elements than css properties directly, then add / remove these classes.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the background style to an empty string should revert it to the style inheriented from the style sheet. This assumes that the default style is from a style sheet, if it isn't you'll have to reset it manually.